# How to (really) cancel a ConnectAsync request on Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, network-programming, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

I'm developing a Windows Phone application that will connect to my server. It does this by using ConnectAsync when you push the login button. But if the server is down and you want to cancel the connecting attempt, what to do?

Here is is the current client code complete with my latest try at shutting the socket connection down. It is to be assumed that you can easily implement a timeout once you know how to turn the connection off.

```
    private IPAddress ServerAddress = new IPAddress(0xff00ff00); //Censored my IP
    private int ServerPort = 13000;
    private Socket CurrentSocket;
    private SocketAsyncEventArgs CurrentSocketEventArgs;
    private bool Connecting = false;

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Connecting)
            {
                CurrentSocket.Close();
                CurrentSocket.Dispose();
                CurrentSocketEventArgs.Dispose();
                CurrentSocket = null;
                CurrentSocketEventArgs = null;
            }
            UserData userdata = new UserData();
            userdata.Username = usernameBox.Text;
            userdata.Password = passwordBox.Password;

            Connecting = ConnectToServer(userdata);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show("Error: " + exception.Message));
        }
    }

    private bool ConnectToServer(UserData userdata)
    {
        CurrentSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        //Create a new SocketAsyncEventArgs
        CurrentSocketEventArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        CurrentSocketEventArgs.RemoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ServerAddress, ServerPort);
        CurrentSocketEventArgs.Completed += ConnectionCompleted;
        CurrentSocketEventArgs.UserToken = userdata;
        CurrentSocketEventArgs.SetBuffer(new byte[1024], 0, 1024);

        CurrentSocket.ConnectAsync(CurrentSocketEventArgs);
        return true;
    }
```

Edit: A thought that struck me is that perhaps it's the server computer that stacks up on requests even though the server software isn't on? Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

I believe

```
socket.Close()
```

should cancel the async connection attempt. There may be some exceptions that need to be caught as a consequence.

Comment: Isn't that what I do already? I haven't had any trouble with exceptions, it's just that they stack up in the background no matter if I use CurrentSocket.Close(). Once I turn on the server it get's a ton of requests all at the same time.

Comment: I believe my answer addresses your main question. What further trouble are you having?

Comment: It's just that even when I use CurrentSocket.Close() as shown in the code the requests pile up. It doesn't seem to work, why is that?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by 'requests pile up'? I assumed your sample code is a client application connecting out?

Comment: Yes, this is the client and it will connect to my server. But if the server is off when you click the button (run the Button_Click method) multiple times things go bad. The requests to connect stack up somewhere, somehow, and once you turn on the server the requests come flooding in. That's the weird part since the client is only supposed to be able to "store" one socket connection request.

Comment: This is the beauty and danger of async programming. If you are calling the method Button_Click multiple times in quick succession you may be creating multiple sockets and potentially not closing them 'ALL' correctly. My next step would be to add a debug method which just closes the current socket and then work out exactly under what combination of circumstances you are having problems.

Comment: Yes, you are propably right. I'll try something like what you say, that is usually the best way to go!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks OK.
As already said by Marc, closing the socket cancels all pending operations.

Yes, it's sometimes possible that you connect OK and nothing happens. To verify, in the command line

`telnet 192.168.1.44 31337` where 192.168.1.44 is ServerAddress (name is OK as well) and 31337 is ServerPort. You might first enable a "Telnet client" using Control Panel/Programs and Features/Turn Windows features on and off. If you see "Could not open connection" = your WinForms application shouldn't be able to connect. If you see a black screen with blinking cursor = your WinForms application should connect OK.

Comment: Thank you for the answer it is much appreciated. The problem isn't the connection however, it has always connected without fault. The code just doesn't seem to want to stop, when I tell it to do so, with CurrentSocket.Close(). It seems like the requests are stacked somehow, somewhere anyway...

Comment: How do you know it didn't stop? And by the way, why are you sending 1024 zero bytes immediately after connection??

Comment: I know it doesn't stop because when I turn on the server, for every click, there is a line written by the server saying "Socket connected". It would explain a lot if my writing new byte[1024] sends a thousand zeroes. I thought it wouldn't send until I started a SendAsync call to the socket...

Answer (score 0):

What's going on here is that you are specifying a buffer in the argument to ConnectAsync.

```
CurrentSocketEventArgs.SetBuffer(new byte[1024], 0, 1024);
```

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/bb538102%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) says:

```
Optionally, a buffer may be provided which will atomically be sent on the socket after the ConnectAsync method succeeds.
```

So your server is going to see the connection and data at once. Your cancellation code is just fine, it's just that the data is sent before you get a chance to cancel anything.